# Prohibit merge-conflicts with deleted files

Tags: git, merge, conflict

Let's say I have a git repository with two or more branches. In branch a I deleted some files:

Branch B (branched off branch A):

```
git rm fileA.txt 
git rm fileB.txt
```

Now we made a lot of changes in branch A. Some of these changes were done in  fileA.txt and/or fileB.txt.
We have to merge branch A into branch B because we need all changes. Now I got conflict with fileA.txt and/or fileB.txt:

```
CONFLICT (modify/delete): fileA.txt ...
```

This ist normal git behaviour. But I don't want that on every merge form branch A into branch B I get these conflicts. It should automaticly accept the deletion of these files.

How can this be done?

Regards, Sascha

Comment: This is possibly the answer you're looking for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10697463/resolve-git-merge-conflicts-in-favor-of-their-changes-during-a-pull

Comment: @MiguelOrtiz: no, `-X theirs` means that when resolving conflicts *within* files, use their changes, but it has no effect on these higher level (tree) conflicts.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot tell Git to prefer the file deletion during the `git merge` run.

What you *can* do is automate the cleaning up of the mess Git leaves behind when the auto-merge *fails*, as after these modify/delete conflicts.

See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50777291/1256452) to a related question: [git rebase conflicts, how to delete all conflicting files that were deleted in the HEAD](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50769302/1256452).

As there, files that you deleted, but they modified, in your `HEAD` commit and in their tip commit, as compared to the merge base commit, will *not* exist at stage 2 in the index, but will exist at stages 1 and 3.

Files that *they* deleted, but that *you* modified, will exist at stages 1 and 2, but not at stage 3.

You can read through the entire index contents, noting which files exist at which stages.  From this, you should determine which files you wish to delete after all.  Use `git rm` to delete them (from all index stages in which they exist, and from the work-tree) and you have resolved those conflicts.  If you write a program to do this, you will have this part all automated:

```
git checkout <branch>             # set up your HEAD
git merge <other>                 # start the merge, which gets conflicts
program-to-clean-up-the-index     # do file-deletions automatically
git status                        # see what's left to do
...                               # do whatever is required
git commit                        # finish the merge
```